# Glade.Нужно сделать автоматическую прокрутку окна

Tags: c, gtk, glade

В контейнер `GtkScrolledWindow` помещены контейнер полосы прокрутки `GtkViewport` в которую помещено окно для взаимодействия с клавой `GtkTextView`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема:**
Я набираю текст, но когда он выходит за пределы этого окошка, то мне приходится самому прокручивать виджет чтобы увидеть что я дальше написал, нужно сделать автоматическую прокрутку окошка , когда текст выходит за его изначальный размер[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось очень просто: Нужно удалить GtkViewport и окно будет автоматически прокручиваться